# Getting embed tag's width/height in Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

I am using the stage ScaleMode as NO_SCALE and want to know the width and height specified in HTML in the embed tag. Is there a way to go about it?
I am using Flash Pro (not flex).

Basically I am trying to keep the UI flexible and hence I want to realign some UI components based on those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using:

```
stage.stageWidth
stage.stageHeight
```

Will give you the total width and height of the SWF as it's been embedded into a page or stretched in Flash Player.

To simplify working with an SWF that can have dynamic width and height, I recommend the following as well:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Comment: wow thanks.. surprisingly I tried this earlier but it didn't work. Anyways.. thanks!!